# User registration event ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I've created an ASP.NET Core 3 website with all the latest updates (Visual Studio 2019). I would like to perform certain actions when a user registers but I cannot find out how to do that. I suspect that I have to hook up to an event in my start up class, but all my googling has left me in loops. Please assist. My current startup class looks like this (it's mostly the generated code)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.TryAddTransient<ITokenService, CustomTokenService>();
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
    services.AddIdentityServer().AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();
    services.AddAuthentication().AddIdentityServerJwt();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
    {
        configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseIdentityServer();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    if (!env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
    }
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the current behavior?

Comment: Could you explain  " I would like to perform certain actions when a user registers " in details ? What's your expected result ?

Comment: At this stage I'm doing a proof of concept website to learn more about ASP Net Core 3, so i don't really have a business case. I may want to add new users to configurations in the app, or send them welcoming emails for example

Comment: My 'use case' is to add a related 'Employee' record to the newly registered user. So what event can I capture, or assign a handler to an event, to do this?